# Online map source to check the geographic coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I am looking for a map source to check the location of the coordinates I was given in latitude/longitude degrees. The coordinates and their corresponding locations are about 20 meters off with respect to each other in some cases, when I check from Google Maps or the sources I list below.

Therefore I am looking for the error range of these sources in order to understand if these deviations stem from the error in the coordinates I have been given, or if the deviations are within the error range of these maps.

(I have been looking at https://epsg.io/ and https://app.dogeo.fr/Projection/#/point-to-coords.)

Comment: Accuracy compated to what?

Comment: What are the "sources"?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you could check Google Maps: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: The question already says that Google Maps has been considered.